# How can we test live video streaming feature of an iOS app , to see if it is working for large audience?

Tags: ios, testing, automation, live, broadcast

There is a requirement for functionally test an iOS application which broadcasts live videos and make sure that it works for a very large audience. Please help.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in this question.  You didn't even tell us what the source of this video is, and how the audience is set up.  (They're not all on the same network, are they?)  What's the distribution protocol even?  The general answer to this question is that you should use a CDN and leave the video distribution up to the professionals who already have a well-tested network.  Then, you can worry about your app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application architecture and what you really want to test. It probably doesn't broadcast directly to clients but through some broadcasting server. 
The question is if you want to test how many broadcast providers can send their stream simultaneously to the server, or you want to test how many end clients can receive a single broadcast from broadcast server. 
For testing client, i would go with jMeter for generating traffic + 1 or 2 devices for manually testing while traffic is generated. 
For testing how many broadcasts can server handle I would go with multiple instances of the OpenBroadcast https://obsproject.com/ application, or also custom jMeter sampler.

Br